# Onchange function is not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Onchange function is not working in Jquery.

In my page i need to add select tag when i click the add button.

My code is here

Using Below code to add a new select tag. This code is working fine.

```
var counter =1;    
var newrow = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'newgroup' + counter);  
var httttm = "";    
httttm += "<td><select name='input_field[]' class='form-control' ><option value=''>Select</option><option value='input'>Text</option><option value='option'>Option</option></select></td></td>";        
newrow.after().html(httttm);
newrow.appendTo("#newgroup");
counter++;
```

Following code is used to get the option value from the select tag. Normally below code is working fine. But when i add the new select tag using above code onchange function is not working.

```
 $('select').change(function (){
    var selvalue = $(this).val();           
    if(selvalue == "option")    {       
        alert("hai");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, You are using direct event binding, Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

As you are creating elements dynamically, use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

i.e.

```
$(staticParentElement).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$('#newgroup').on('change', "select", function(){
    var selvalue = $(this).val();           
    if(selvalue == "option")    {       
        alert("hai");
    }
});
```

Comment: Its working fine thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You need to delegate event using `.on()` to bind change event for dynamically generated elements

```
$(document).on("change", 'select',function (){
    var selvalue = $(this).val();           
    if(selvalue == "option")    {       
        alert("hai");
    }
 });
```